# What does the Moilian Barrow monster in the Tomb of Horrors Super Adventure look like?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

From the read aloud text of encounter M3: Dark Barrow on p55 of the Tomb of Horrors Super Adventure:

*Bones and body parts are knitting themselves together into a larger mass in the rubble.*

There doesn't appear to be any art in the book illustrating this critter. Are there similar monsters in other books with illustrations? I'm having trouble visualizing what this thing is supposed to look like.

Comment: Here is a [Moilian Heart](http://www.lomion.de/cmm/moilhear.php) and a [Moilian Zombie](http://www.lomion.de/cmm/moilzomb.php).  The existance of the heart suggests that it doesn't have to be humanoid in shape -- it can be a nightmarish [shoggoth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoggoth) of human remnants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, it sounds like a variant on a Flesh Golem.  Probably with less emphasis on a humanoid shape.

Something like [this guy](http://lordnetsua.deviantart.com/art/Flesh-Golem-169207352).

Comment: @Iszi - Rolled back.  I do not own that image and the artist has clearly reserved all rights.

Comment: Who has two thumbs, eight arms, a tentacle, and is missing a face? [This guy!](http://lordnetsua.deviantart.com/art/Flesh-Golem-169207352)  (and [for reference](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HasTwoThumbsAnd))

Comment: Sorry about that.  Thought the inclusion of copyright notice and URL in the image itself pretty much covered all the basis.

Answer (score 2):

There was the Devourer's Spawn in Dragon Magazine 371, page 14. In my opinion they're the same thing, but it was just renamed to Barrow when the super adventure was made.

Bottom right corner https://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4art/20090130